# Responsive Webdesign - Performance optimisation

Tags: html, css, optimization, responsive-design

my new website is now finally finished and it runs pretty smooth, on most devices i tested. the only thing I optimized was the code, so i deleted all comments and other unnessescary lines in all .css and .html files. but beyond that, what else can i do to optimise a website specific for mobile contextes?

you can see here here (all images are only used for demonstration): http://mbaljan.de/weblab/sites/designtisch/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug "page speed" provides lot of optimization options . You can try them .[image: page speed]

Answer (score 0):

You consider changing what is being served to the browser based on either internet connection speed or device or both. For example, serve smaller images when the website is being viewed on a mobile device. That would speed up the load time. Check out Adaptive Images to do that: http://adaptive-images.com/

Apart from that, trying to reduce the number of files being loaded is a good idea. E.g. 1 jQuery/javascript file. You can also try to minify all your javascript files (and CSS if you really want to) to reduce their files sizes and decrease load time. If you intend to modify those files again in future you'd have to keep an uncompressed backup though. 
Check out: http://javascriptcompressor.com/

Another thing you could make sure you're doing is using image sprites. That way you reduce the number of image files being loaded. This won't work with Adaptive Images, so I find it best to use sprites just for things like logos and icons.